# scroll lock modifier for arrow keys

Tags: scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Most laptops these days have the <kbd>Page up</kbd>/<kbd>Page down</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys as <kbd>Fn</kbd> overlays of the arrow keys. It has always been a minor annoyance that <kbd>Fn</kbd> is on the other side of the keyboard, making one-handed use of the <kbd>Page up</kbd> etc. nearly impossible.

I recently thought of the idea of using <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> as a modifier, so that if scroll lock is on, the arrow keys would always be <kbd>Page up</kbd> etc. Here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'

arrow() {
    echo "arrow mode";
    xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right"
}
page() {
    echo "page mode";
    xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Prior NoSymbol Prior"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 116 = Next NoSymbol Next"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 113 = Home NoSymbol Home"
    xmodmap -e "keycode 114 = End NoSymbol End"
}

arrow;

trap 'arrow; exit 255;' EXIT SIGINT

slock0="";
echo $slock;
while true; do
    slock="$(xset -q | sed -ne '/Scroll Lock/s/^.*Scroll Lock: \([a-z]*\).*$/\1/p')";
    if [ "$slock" != "$slock0" ]; then 
        slock0="$slock";
        if [ "$slock" == "on" ]; then
            page
        else
            arrow
        fi
    fi
    sleep 0.5
done
```

I'm just curious if there is a more elegant way to do this? Is there a problem with running `xmodmap` so frequently?

In the past I have dedicated a key (such as <kbd>Menu</kbd> between right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) as the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, and done `xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Prior"`, etc. However my current laptop doesn't have a "free" key in that region. And I'm not familiar with a way to make the scroll lock act like the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is totally fine, there are just some minor things I’d change:

- `xmodmap` allows you to specify multiple expressions per command line, so instead of calling it four times your can call it only once per function
- `printf "%s\n" "$slock"` won’t print an empty line if `slock` is empty
- `grep -oP 'Scroll Lock:\s*\K\w+'` does the same as your `sed` command, but if you insist on using `sed`:

  ```bsh
  sed -nr 's/.*Scroll Lock:\s*(\w+).*/\1/p'
  ```
- `while :` is the same as `while true` – it’s a matter of taste I guess

#### Script with changes

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'

arrow() {
  echo "arrow mode"
  xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Up NoSymbol Up" \
          -e "keycode 116 = Down NoSymbol Down" \
          -e "keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Left" \
          -e "keycode 114 = Right NoSymbol Right"
}
page() {
  echo "page mode"
  xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Prior NoSymbol Prior" \
          -e "keycode 116 = Next NoSymbol Next" \
          -e "keycode 113 = Home NoSymbol Home" \
          -e "keycode 114 = End NoSymbol End"
}

arrow
trap 'arrow; exit 255;' EXIT SIGINT

printf "%s\n" "$slock"
while :; do
  slock="$(xset -q | grep -oP 'Scroll Lock:\s*\K\w+')"
  if [ "$slock" != "$slock0" ]; then
    slock0="$slock"
    if [ "$slock" = "on" ]; then
      page
    else
      arrow
    fi
  fi
sleep 0.5
done
```

I suggest to even change the delay to `sleep 1` – personally, I find that by far fast enough, and it saves your machine half the calls. Try what suits your needs.